# .NET Framework v4.5 Changing Layout Of Program

Tags: c#, .net, layout, treeview

I have a program that I developed in C# and it is currently running on the Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0. I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and that also installed Microsoft .NET Framework v4.5. Before when I had .NET Framework v4.0 installed, this how my program looked:

[image: With MS .NET Framework v4.0]

Now that I upgraded to .NET Framework v4.5, this is how it looks:

[image: With MS .NET Framework v4.5]

Notice the TreeView is now on the right side instead of the left? The 2 controls are each in seperate columns in a table which is in tool strip container. This problem is occurring on the latest/stable version of .NET Framework v4.5 (v4.0.30319.17929 or v4.5.50709 to be exact) which was released on August 15. I would like to know what is causing this and if there's a way to prevent this from happening (besides uninstalling .NET Framework v4.5)? Also, if this program is compiled with v4.0, why is v4.5 causing this problem?

Comment: The *why* question in your last sentence? Because 4.5 is an in place upgrade of 4.0. The 4.0 framework binaries are changed by this upgrade. In the same way the 3.0 and 3.5 made changes to some 2.0 binaries.

Comment: Can you post enough code from the UI to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RyanGates The code is located at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lrc-team/lilregcleaner/devel/files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling it and running it under v4.0? Just because 4.5 is installed it doesn't mean 4.0 has been uninstalled.

In your solution explorer, right click on the project name and click Properties. Then in the Application tab, set the Target framework back to .NET Framework 4.

Then compile and run. If it's a .NET framework thing then it should all be back to normal. If it's still docked to the right, then the code has changed somehow.